# How can I set an href for a link to equal a variable inside my script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following markup to show an image inside a jQuery slider:-

```
<li>
    <figure> <a href="~/img/big.jpg" class="thumb">
                <img src="~/img/small.jpg" alt=""/>
                <span>
                    <strong>Project name:</strong><em>Villa</em>
                    <img src="~/img/searchsmall.png" alt="" 
                       data-goto="@Url.Action("OurProjects", "Home", new { name = "villaA" })"/>
                </span>
            </a>

    </figure>
</li>
```

Inside a call back function which loads the image inside the slider, I want to add a new `<a>` inside the current placeholder where the href for the link equals the data-goto value.

I tried the following,

```
  function loadImage(src, callback) {
      var img = $('<img>').on('load', function () {
          callback.call(img);
      });

      img.attr('src', src);
      var allcaptions = $("figure span");

      // setTimeout is a hack here, since the ".placeholders" don't exist yet
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(".placeholder").each(function (i) {

              // in each .placeholder, copy its caption's mark-up into it
              // (remove the img first)
              var caption = allcaptions.eq(i).clone();

              var t = $(this).find("img").attr('data-goto');

              caption.append("<a href=t>test</a>");
              caption.find("img").remove();
              $(this).append("<div class='caption'>" + caption.html() + "</div>");
          });
      }, 500);
  }
```

but the generated link will have "undefined" as its href.

**EDIT**

The placeholder class will be inside the jquery slider , as follows

[image: Rendered markup]

**EDIT-2**

here is the markup when the page loads :-

```
<li>
    <figure> 
        <a href="~/img/big.jpg" class="thumb">
            <img src="~/img/small.jpg" alt=""/>
            <span>
                <strong>Project name:</strong><em>Villa</em>
                <img src="~/img/searchsmall.png" alt="" 
                     data-goto="@Url.Action("OurProjects", "Home", new { name = "villaA" })"/>
            </span>
        </a>
    </figure>
</li>
```

now when you click on `small.jpg` image , the big.jpg will be shown inside the slider. Here is the markup inside the slider

```
<div id="galleryOverlay" class="visible" style="display: block;">
<div id="gallerySlider" style="left: 0%;">
<div class="placeholder">
<img src="/img/big.jpg">
<div class="caption">
<div class="caption">
<strong>Project name: </strong>
<em>Villa</em>
<img data-goto="/OurProjects?name=villaA" alt="" src="/img/searchsmall.png">
<a>test</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="placeholder">
<div class="placeholder">
<div class="placeholder">
<div class="placeholder">
<div class="placeholder">
<div class="placeholder">
<div class="placeholder">
<div class="placeholder">
```

where the link will not have a href or the href will be undefined. Is this my problem?

**EDIT-3**

here is the firbug screen
[image: Firebug image of the rendered HTML]

Comment: It will have `t` as its href, not `undefined`.

Comment: @Barmar currently "var t = $(this).find("img").attr('data-goto');" is returning undefined ... although i am saying to find the img and then get its data-goto attribute ..! not sure why this is not working ?

Comment: Where is `class="placeholder"` in your HTML?

Comment: where is the element with class name `placeholder`?

Comment: @Barmar: :) congratulations on 200k

Comment: @Barmar placeholder will be inside the jquery slider , please check my edit i provided a screenshot from my firebug ..

Comment: @naveen the placeholder will be inside the jquery slider ,, where i am appending all the elements i want to it ,, please check my edit i provided a screen from firebug , thanks

Comment: please expand the `class="caption"` `div`

Comment: The `img` in your screenshot doesn't have a `data-goto` attribute.

Comment: because inside my script i remove it " caption.find("img").remove();" ? because i do not want the slider to show the search icon searchsmall.png.. did u get my point ?thanks

Comment: This is getting confusing. I don't see how the DOM in the screenshot relates to the HTML in the question. You need to show what the DOM looks like BEFORE the code runs, not after.

Comment: @Barmar sorry for the confusing please check edit-2 section i provided the markup inside the web page and inside the slider ..

Comment: That markup doesn't look right. You have two `<div class="caption">`, and there's lots of missing `</div>`. I guess you're trying to abbreviate, but you left out too much.

Comment: @Barmar no i just copied the markup from firebug directly, so the other caption is for another image. and all the DIV have closing tags but i did not shown them.. please check edit-3 i provided a screen shot directly from firebug .thanks

Comment: @Barmar what i am doing is that inside the script i am saying to find the img and retrieve its data-goto  , then to build a link which have the data-goto has its href, now as shown the link will be shown so my procedure is correct but the "var t = $(this).find("img").attr('data-goto');
" is not able to retrieve the data-goto value ?

Comment: If you're getting `undefined`, then it's either not finding the `img` or the `img` doesn't have a `data-goto` attribute. Try setting a breakpoint in the code and examining the values of the variables

Comment: Can yo make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: the problem was that i need to get the data-goto as follow: "var t = caption.find("img").attr('data-goto');"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String concatenation is done using `+` operator.

```
caption.append("<a href='" + t + "'>test</a>");
```

The resultant anchor tag will look like following if `t = 'https://jsfiddle.net'

```
<a href='https://jsfiddle.net'>test</a>
```

Comment: seems the " var t = $(this).find("img").attr('data-goto');" will be undefined not sure why ? not sure why ? could the problem is that i am using Url.Action to be the href inside the data-goto?

Comment: seems i need to get the data-goto as follow "var t = caption.find("img").attr('data-goto');"

Answer (score 1):

`t` appear to be `String` at `caption.append("<a href=t>test</a>");` , not reference to `t` variable at previous line . Try using `attributes` parameter of [`jQuery( html, attributes )`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes) to set `text` , `href` properties.

```
var t = $(this).find("img").attr('data-goto');
caption.append($("<a />", {"text":"test", "href":t}));
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,, but using this approach the generated a will not have any href here is the generated link :- <div class="caption">
<strong>Project name: </strong>
<em> Villa</em>
<a>test</a>
</div>

Comment: @guest2713114 seems that in my case the variable t will be undefined :-" var t = $(this).find("img").attr('data-goto');"

Comment: @johnG What is expected result ?

Comment: the expected result is to have the link href equal to "@Url.Action("OurProjects", "Home", new { name = "villaA" })" which should be "/Home/OurProjects?name=villaA"

Comment: Tried using string "/Home/OurProjects?name=villaA" ?

Comment: yes same problem ,, i will get undefined for the t when i tired " var t = $(this).find("img").attr('data-goto');"

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the string in t correctly.
`caption.append("<a href=\""+t+"\">test</a>");`